# Intent returning Null for Rasa nlu

Tags: rasa-nlu

I am currently running into an issue where if the user types a word that has not been trained in the nlu file, the nlu will return this:

```
"intent": {
   "name": null,
   "confidence": 0.0
}
```

With other scenarios, it works great! Is there a way to capture these errors and have rasa return the default error message? Please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unclear how you are using this nlu response.

1. If you are using it in rasa_core, you can capture & handle any such intent beforehand in your Custom Action Class.
   e.g.

```
def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
        intent  = tracker.latest_message.intent["name"]
```

2. If you want to do it at rasa_nlu level itself, go to rasa_nlu installation directory (usually it is in "Python install folder"\Lib\site-packages\rasa_nlu\ and make below changes in model.py

```
def default_output_attributes():
        return {"intent": {"name": None, "confidence": 0.0}, "entities": []}
```

to

```
 def default_output_attributes():
        return {"intent": {"name": "YOUR_CUSTOM_NAME", "confidence": 0.0}, "entities": []}
```

But please be cautioned in using second one. You may have to take care while upgrading rasa_nlu python package.

Comment: Hi @mvs thank you for your response! I apologize for the confusion. The problem that I am encountering is that the intent is recognized as null, I am unable to add this to the stories.md file thus rasa yells at me. Is there a way for me to add this to the stories or somehow capture this null intent and force it to go to a default?

Comment: One way to do it can be through a fallback mechanism.

include some training that do not relate to your use case and add them under an intent fallback.
when RASA NLU could not categorize anything as your use case, it'll put it under fallback intent. Then you can define a story for a fallback intent.
hope it helps. cheers!

Comment: Another but less recommended way you can try is to use point 2 in my answer & define a story based on _YOUR_CUSTOM_INTENT._

Comment: thank you! I thought about creating the custom intent and adding this words here. But I am curious, do you know if there is a way for rasa core to recognize this null intent or take some default faultback action? I am thinking I can try to add as many use cases as possible on the custom intent, however, I am worried that a user might have a use case i didnt think of and crash the bot!

Comment: welcome :)
seems they didn't implement any configurable option to do it, as i checked on github page.
As far as my experience goes, you need not add many things to fallback. Just add few things that are unrelated to your bot scenario. It should serve the purpose well. Combined with confidence threshhold, you can make it work in respectable way.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you again for your help this helped me a lot!